# Finding pass rate in Excel within a date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, countif, sumifs

I have a large control sheet in Excel with over 1000+ students on it. I have three columns that I want to use which are (Start of 2 year study period - column 1), (End of 2 year study period - column 2) and (Pass/No Pass - column 3)

When a learner registers with us we will type in the start date of registration in the first column and then +730 for the 2nd column giving us our end date.

In the pass no pass column each learner has to complete units and when they pass this unit I mark it as a pass.

What I want to try and achieve / find out is pass rates either

- A. per year or
- B. every two years (registration period)

For example if I registered say 200 students between 01/01/2015 and 01/01/2017 I want to know what the code for that would be - if there is any code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `=COUNTIF(C:C,"Yes")/(COUNTA(A:A)-1)` would do it where "Yes" means they have passed (if you want, you can change this to "passed" etc.).

The above formula puts the total number of "Yes"'s over the total number of people registered (`COUNTA(A:A)-1` counts all cells with an entry and then takes away the header)

Here's what it's look like:

**EDIT: Please forget the dates entered in column B - I just entered random dates so these aren't correct but the formula works perfectly regardless.**

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for this! so i used your code and its coming up with a high percentage as the dates on my spreadsheet range back from 2012 or further. 

heres what the columns im using and the area the pass rate is

http://s1193.photobucket.com/user/inzid/media/1.jpg.html - with code at the top

http://s1193.photobucket.com/user/inzid/media/2.jpg.html

http://s1193.photobucket.com/user/inzid/media/3.jpg.html

Is there anyway to get the pass rate percentage between years? say 2015 pass rate, 2016 pass rate etc

Comment: you should be able to do a per year analysis with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do an analysis per year you can use the following helper column D.

Column A: Start date formatted as date (localization doesn't matter)
Column B: `=A:A+730`
Column D: `=YEAR(A:A)` (format as standard or number)
G3: `=COUNTIFS(D:D,"=2016",C:C,"=Pass")`
G4: `=COUNTIFS(D:D,"=2016")`

If you need a 2 year analysis (eg. 2016+2017) do an analysis for both years and add them up later. Then calculate the rate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peh, I tried the Column D but its not pulling over the year correctly. I have formatted the K column (my start dates) as 'Date'

Comment: Then use `=YEAR(K:K)` if this is your year column? `A:A` means column A so `K:K` means column K.

Comment: Yeah tried that `=YEAR(K:K)` and it just comes up with the date 09/07/1905

Comment: Format the year column with the formula `=YEAR(K:K)` as standard (or number) not as date

Comment: Hi Peh, a quick question - how do i get the =YEAR(K:K) to work if youve merged cells. My next problem is i have one learner but with multiple rows. if i merge them so the year date is 2016 for each row i create the pass or no pass only works for the first row